# sftp file download script

Tags: bash, sftp

I am trying to download a from from a remote sftp location so for this I am using below script.

```
#!/bin/bash
expect -c "
spawn sftp remoteUser@xx.xx.xx.xx
expect \"password\"
send \"User@123\r\"
interact "
```

The problem is in the remote server some information msg configure when you login the server, so because of this password send before this text comes on screen.

Comment: what if after you send password do `expect \"remoteUser@xx.xx.xx.xx:\"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
export PASSD="User@123"
expect -c 'spawn sftp user@xxxxxx.com; 
expect "*Password: ";
send "$env(PASSD)\r";
expect "sftp>";
send "cd /home/user \r";
expect "sftp>";
send "get file.txt \r";
expect "sftp>";
send "bye \r"'
```

Comment: Actually they have set some privacy policy which comes on screen before the password prompt and hold the screen for 60 seconds. our password send before the password asking prompt comes.

Comment: @DeepeshUniyal - Check my updated Answer. It will work to ignore the company's p.p. message.

Comment: Thank, The reason is different, expect command has default timeout 10 sec, remote server holding for 60 sec. before password prompt window. now I set it 'set timeout 100'. now its working fine.